# Как оставить выбранный элемент на другой странице? vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli

Имеется попап, с некоторыми элементами (item.name)

```
<div class='regions-list__popup' v-if='toggle'>
 <a v-for='item in resultQuery' :key='item.seo_name' :href='item.link' class='regions-list__name' @click='selectLink(item.name)'>{{
        item.name
      }}</a>
</div>
```

Кнопка, которая вызывает попап и записывает `selected`

```
<button @click='toggle = !toggle'>{{ selected }}</button>
```

vue, отвечающий за запись в `selected`

```
data() {
 return {
  toggle: false,
  selected: 'Default'
 };
},
methods: {
 selectLink(link) {
  this.selected = link;
 }
}
```

При переходе на другую страницу, очевидно, пропадает из поля `selected` выбранный элемент `item.name`.
Что нужно добавить (и куда копать), дабы выбранный элемент оставался на следующей странице?

Comment: Копайте в сторону Vuex

Comment: @Дмытрык Это единственный путь решения? (использование vuex)

Comment: Нет, можно через localstorage, vue-router, в адресной строке инфу передать, еще можно через сервер

Comment: Совсем забыл, еще можно в а глобальном объекте window инфу сохранить